# bash uniq, how to show count number at back

Tags: bash, unix

Normally when I do `cat number.txt | sort -n | uniq -c` , I get numbers like this:

```
3 43
4 66
2 96
1 97
```

But what I need is the number shows of occurrences at the back, like this:

```
43 3
66 4
96 2
97 1
```

Please give advice on how to change this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk` to change the order of columns:

```
cat number.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

Comment: ...if you're using awk, surely you should be handling the sorting and uniqing from there too!

Comment: ... and the `cat`ing even.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I just tacked it on the end to get the desired output. UNIX tools are for hacking, right? I've been researching to remember how to do those things with `awk` :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thankfully, I find Perl easier to remember than awk (see my answer). Then again, I haven't done any serious coding with awk, so.

Comment: @hawk That won't get you the occurrence count.

Answer (score 3):

Perl version:

```
perl -lne '$occ{0+$_}++; END {print "$_ $occ{$_}" for sort {$a <=> $b} keys %occ}' < numbers.txt
```

Comment: You can use the `-n` option to remove the `while <>` and move the printing to `END` block by stating `}{` (shorthand) or write an explicit `END` block. For eg: `perl -ne '$occ{0+$_}++ }{ print "$_ $occ{$_}\n" for sort {$a <=> $b} keys %occ' numbers.txt`. I am sure you know this already but may be useful for others but +1 for all-in-one solution.

Comment: @jaypal Yes, I knew about `-n` and `END`, and I almost used that. I should probably put that in my answer. In recent years I've been using Ruby more, where `END` is seldom-used, so I've gotten out of the habit of using it in Perl, also.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. There is another `perl` switch `-l` which removes the new line from the end before processing the `$_` and places it back when we print. So when used in above case we can also remove the explicit `\n` from `print`. Just FYI .. `:)`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisJester-Young. Appreciate the edits and congratulations in advance for reaching 100k. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal Thanks! I did [hit 100k for real today](https://plus.google.com/104178729694994695707/posts/cDbKRT2s89H), so thanks for the congrats. :-D

Comment: Awesome!! [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is just half a million rep ahead now. Bring it on! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

Through GNU `sed`,

```
cat number.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)$/\2 \1/g'
```